# Display the button set to active on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I need some help turning my sidebar buttons into dropdown upon responsive. Something close to this sidebar (left) here in this website: http://www.isoentertainmentinfo.com/

If possible, can it be done that when it turns into dropdown, only the active button will be displayed, and that when you click on that active dropdown, the others would show? Something close to what the website above has, but in my case, buttons are being changed to active on click, rather than loading an entirely new page.

Here is what I have for my links:

```
<div class="buttonRow">
        <ul class="btn">
        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Active Link Here</label> ***display only upon dropdown***
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 1 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 2 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 3 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 4 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 5 </li></button>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've already got the adding active class upon click. I just need that active class to be the only one displayed as the main text of the dropdown.

Here's a visual example to make it clearer, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI5NI.png)

Thank you so much. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I am not a `CSS` guy but you need to create the media-query for the resolution you want to display the dropdowns and for that, you need to hide the menu and show the select drop-down or maybe someone else could give a better solution. you can search google how to write mediaqueries.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer. I've already got the dropdown thing done, but it's main header remains as "active link here" since I can't figure out how to replace that with the text on the actual active class instead. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
       $('button').toggle();
  });
  // set a varable for text
  var $text;   
  $('.btnAbt2').click(function(){ 
       // get the text from the link clicked 
       $text = $(this).text()
       $('.btnAbt2').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');
       // update the lable text
       $('.toggle').text($text);
  });
 
});
```

```css
.buttonRow {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #CCC;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .toggle {
       display: none;
    }
    button {
       width: auto;
       float: left;
       display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonRow">
        <ul class="btn">
        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Active Link Here</label> 
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 1 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 2 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 3 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 4 </li></button>
            <button class="btnAbt2"><li> Link 5 </li></button>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it is close! Almost similar to what I currently have, all I have to do is replace the text on .drop with "Active Link Here" with the current button class that has .active on it. Here's my jQuery for it.

`jQuery('.btnAbt2').click(function(){
 
 jQuery('.btnAbt2').removeClass('active');

  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});`

I'm sorry I don't know how to format it better :( Thank you for your time